# Is there a namespace for the current module?

Tags: haskell, module, scope

My problem is in the last line:

```
module A where

data A = A { f :: Int }

defaultA = A { f = 0 }
```

and

```
module B where

import A as A

data B = B { f :: Int }

bToA :: B -> A
bToA x = defaultA { A.f = f x }
```

gives

```
B.hs:8:26:
    Ambiguous occurrence `f'
    It could refer to either `B.f', defined at B.hs:5:13
                          or `A.f', imported from A at B.hs
```

Since i can not include B qualified within itself, what alternative is there to resolve the namespace clash? I would rather not rename the clashing function.

Edit: updated that examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import qualified A as A
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd do it this way:

```
module B where

import A hiding (A(..))
import qualified A as A

bToA x = defaultA { A.f = f x }
```

This way you could access all non-clashing names from A without prepending 'A.' and all clashing names are imported with full qualification - as 'A.something'. You retain brevity of code and work around the conflicts.

Of course, simplier `import qualified Some.Long.Name as S` would also work if you don't mind prepending 'S.' everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Just `B.f`

And you don't need

```
import A as A
```

Just

```
import A
```

Comment: How to refer to `defaultA` if the module doesn't `import A`?

Comment: Hm, that works, thanks. In my real-life example the module names are quiet long that's why was looking for a "import Foo as F" style solution.